# Get category "Date" in Excel when writing data from pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a dataframe into an excel, but I specifically need the column (in excel) to be of category "Date".

What I'm trying to achieve therefore is:

```
x = pandas.DataFrame(data=['04/01/2020'], columns=['Date'])
x.to_excel("<path>/ExcelFile.xlsx")
```

This gives me the following:
[image]

I would like to have the "General" category marked as Date by default when I load the Excel file.

I cannot do this manually, because there are hundreds of files that need the same treatment.

I have tried the following:

```
x['Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(x['Date'])
```

which gives me:

[image]

But that gives me in the Excel, category "Custom".

Any suggestions on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pd.ExcelWriter, class for writing DataFrame objects into excel sheets:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame(data=['04/01/2020'], columns=['Date'])
x['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(x['Date'])

with pd.ExcelWriter('<path>/ExcelFile.xlsx', datetime_format='DD/MM/YYYY') as writer:
    x.to_excel(writer)
```

You should see 'date' format when you open the file. You didn't specify what is a day and a month in your case, but you can set it with 'datetime_format' as you want.